# jQuery defaultValue in dropdownlist in form load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to default the drop down value on form load using jQuery.
When I use this `$("#FORM_COMPANY").val("All");` drop down value is defaulted but when declare variable something like below

```
var defaultValue= "somevalue";

$("#FORM_COMPANY").val(defaultValue);
```

then dropdown is not defaulted, can any one help

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would include your select.

Comment: Yeah, show us your `html`

Comment: I'm getting my option values dynamically

Answer (score 2):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var defaultValue= "All";
    
     $("#FORM_COMPANY").val(defaultValue);
    });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select id="FORM_COMPANY">
     <option value="">Select Value</option>
     <option value="All">All</option>
     <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: great answer,keep it up

Comment: You should always add an explanation on why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for 100% sure without getting to see your `<select>` and `<option>` list, but based on the details only from your question I can assume that you're trying to assign a default value that contains a string that is not present among your value attribute in `<option value="???">`

```js
 
$=jQuery;
var firstDefaultValue = 'first';
$('#FORM_COMPANY1').val(firstDefaultValue);
// Will work, because inside your <select> there is an option with value="first"

var secondDefaultValue = 'IamNotListedInAnyOption';
$('#FORM_COMPANY2').val(secondDefaultValue);
// Will NOT work, because inside your <select> there is NO option with value="IamNotListedInAnyOption"
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="FORM_COMPANY1">
 <option value="default">Select Value</option>
 <option value="first">First</option>
 <option value="second">Second</option>
</select>
<select id="FORM_COMPANY2">
 <option value="default">Select Value</option>
 <option value="first">First</option>
 <option value="second">Second</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting my option values dynamically from sql table, drop down is loaded with values from sql but I want default drop down value based on user logged in

Comment: Then make sure that the value you put into your `var defaultValue` matches with the value from at least one `<option>` from this dropdown

Comment: yes it is matching but drop down is not defaulted to value. its default value coming as blank

Comment: Then please share with us the full content of your `<selecet>` and what value exactly are you want to set as default